# SwiftUI - proper use of @available() and #available

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Am I missing something in the following code?

This app builds (macOS Monterey b5 / Xcode 13 b5) and executes perfectly on an iOS 15 device -- but causes a SIGABRT on an iOS 14.7 device...

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "This app causes a runtime error on ios 14.7"
    @available(iOS 15.0, *)
    @FocusState var isInputActive: Bool

    var body: some View {

        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .focused($isInputActive)
        } else {    //  ios14 or <
            TextEditor(text: $text)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is the `dyld: Symbol not found` issue - I filed radar `FB9370523` back on 20th July (2021), with less than 10 similar reports and 'potential fix in iOS 15' - which obviously doesn't help. But even in the latest Xcode betas, this is still a problem. No solution as of yet. If you also file a radar and reference mine there is a higher chance of this being fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Was faced same issue and found solution by keeping property values in view modifier.

Here I give simple example :

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct TextEditor: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
           content
           .font(.largeTitle)
           .foregroundColor(.white)
           .padding()
           .background(.blue)
        
    }
}
```

Then call as below :

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *){
    Text("Hello world").modifier(TextEditor())
}
```