# Swiftui app crashes with different SearchBar (ViewModifier) on iOS 14 / 15

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am using SwiftlySearch on iOS 14 and .searchable on iOS 15.

```
struct CompatibleSearchBarModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            content.searchable(text: self.$text, prompt: "Placeholder")
                
        } else {
            content.navigationBarSearch(self.$text, placeholder: "Placeholder", hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling: true, cancelClicked: {text = ""})
        }
    }
}
```

The app crashes on iOS 14.7.1-14.8 devices based on Crashlytics. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem on Xcode 13.2.1 since I can't use these iOS versions on the simulator (I tried this library without any success: https://github.com/JinjunHan/iOSDeviceSupport). Any ideas what could I do in this situation?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x313dbc swift::ResolveAsSymbolicReference::operator()(swift::Demangle::__runtime::SymbolicReferenceKind, swift::Demangle::__runtime::Directness, int, void const*)
1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x33170c swift::Demangle::__runtime::Demangler::demangleSymbolicReference(unsigned char)
2  libswiftCore.dylib             0x32e970 swift::Demangle::__runtime::Demangler::demangleType(__swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef, std::__1::function<swift::Demangle::__runtime::Node* (swift::Demangle::__runtime::SymbolicReferenceKind, swift::Demangle::__runtime::Directness, int, void const*)>)
3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x31935c swift_getTypeByMangledNameImpl(swift::MetadataRequest, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef, void const* const*, std::__1::function<swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const* (unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::__1::function<swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const* (swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, unsigned int)>)
4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x316d58 swift::swift_getTypeByMangledName(swift::MetadataRequest, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef, void const* const*, std::__1::function<swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const* (unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::__1::function<swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const* (swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, unsigned int)>)
5  libswiftCore.dylib             0x316f6c swift_getTypeByMangledNameInContext
6  Menetrend                      0xb7b0 __swift_instantiateConcreteTypeFromMangledName + 4331173808 (<compiler-generated>:4331173808)
7  Menetrend                      0x205750 CompatibleSearchBarModifier.body(content:) + 1107 (FavouritesView.swift:1107)
8  SwiftUI                        0x60a160 partial apply for closure #1 in ModifierBodyAccessor.updateBody(of:changed:)
9  SwiftUI                        0x62c364 closure #1 in BodyAccessor.setBody(_:)
10 SwiftUI                        0x609a64 ModifierBodyAccessor.updateBody(of:changed:)
11 SwiftUI                        0x62c770 DynamicBody.updateValue()
12 SwiftUI                        0x32f764 partial apply for implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:)
13 AttributeGraph                 0x5108 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update()
14 AttributeGraph                 0x5518 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool)
15 AttributeGraph                 0xa718 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long)
16 AttributeGraph                 0x1b3c0 AGGraphGetValue
17 SwiftUI                        0x972c80 _ConditionalContent<>.ChildView.content.getter
18 SwiftUI                        0x972e20 _ConditionalContent<>.ChildView.value.getter
19 SwiftUI                        0x972f30 protocol witness for Rule.value.getter in conformance _ConditionalContent<A, B><>.ChildView
20 SwiftUI                        0x23e6e0 implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:)
21 AttributeGraph                 0x5108 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update()
22 AttributeGraph                 0x5518 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool)
23 AttributeGraph                 0xa718 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long)
24 AttributeGraph                 0x1b3c0 AGGraphGetValue
25 SwiftUI                        0x62fec8 AnyViewList.updateValue()
26 SwiftUI                        0x205f0c partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:)
27 AttributeGraph                 0x5108 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update()
28 AttributeGraph                 0x5518 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool)
29 AttributeGraph                 0xa718 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long)
30 AttributeGraph                 0x1b3c0 AGGraphGetValue
31 SwiftUI                        0x4661e8 DynamicLayoutViewAdaptor.updatedItems()
32 SwiftUI                        0x4cac4 specialized DynamicContainerInfo.updateItems(disableTransitions:)
33 SwiftUI                        0x4b854 specialized DynamicContainerInfo.updateValue()
34 SwiftUI                        0x1c924c partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:)
35 AttributeGraph                 0x5108 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update()
36 AttributeGraph                 0x5518 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool)
37 AttributeGraph                 0xa718 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long)
38 AttributeGraph                 0x1b3c0 AGGraphGetValue
39 SwiftUI                        0x328b5c DynamicPreferenceCombiner.info.getter
40 SwiftUI                        0x328d00 DynamicPreferenceCombiner.value.getter
41 SwiftUI                        0x23e6e0 implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:)
42 AttributeGraph                 0x5108 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update()
43 AttributeGraph                 0x5518 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool)
44 AttributeGraph                 0xa718 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long)
45 AttributeGraph                 0x1b3c0 AGGraphGetValue
46 SwiftUI                        0x5d7510 HostPreferencesTransform.updateValue()
47 SwiftUI                        0x32f764 partial apply for implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:)
48 AttributeGraph                 0x5108 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update()
49 AttributeGraph                 0x5518 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool)
50 AttributeGraph                 0xa718 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long)
51 AttributeGraph                 0x1b3c0 AGGraphGetValue
52 SwiftUI                        0x5d7510 HostPreferencesTransform.updateValue()
53 SwiftUI                        0x32f764 partial apply for implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:)
54 AttributeGraph                 0x5108 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update()
55 AttributeGraph                 0x5518 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool)
56 AttributeGraph                 0xa718 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long)
57 AttributeGraph                 0x1b3c0 AGGraphGetValue
58 SwiftUI                        0x7e4d0 specialized HostPreferencesTransform.updateValue()
59 SwiftUI                        0x1e4590 partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:)
60 AttributeGraph                 0x5108 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update()
61 AttributeGraph                 0x5518 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool)
62 AttributeGraph                 0xa1a8 AG::Graph::value_ref(AG::AttributeID, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*)
63 AttributeGraph                 0x1b408 AGGraphGetValue
64 SwiftUI                        0x8e9f38 GraphHost.preferenceValues()
65 SwiftUI                        0x84fcec specialized GraphHost.preferenceValue<A>(_:)
66 SwiftUI                        0x84aacc specialized ViewRendererHost.updateViewGraph<A>(body:)
67 SwiftUI                        0x6463c specialized closure #1 in UINavigationController.update<A>(with:in:)
68 SwiftUI                        0x45cf40 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> ()
69 SwiftUI                        0x84ed74 closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:)
70 SwiftUI                        0x84ae68 ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:)
71 SwiftUI                        0x9a7654 _UIHostingView.layoutSubviews()
72 SwiftUI                        0x9a7680 @objc _UIHostingView.layoutSubviews()
73 UIKitCore                      0x102f8bc -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
74 QuartzCore                     0x15e424 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
75 QuartzCore                     0x164bac CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
76 QuartzCore                     0x17016c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
77 QuartzCore                     0xb8578 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
78 QuartzCore                     0xe32c8 CA::Transaction::commit()
79 UIKitCore                      0xb4d8b0 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2
80 CoreFoundation                 0x9ad08 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
81 CoreFoundation                 0x99f9c __CFRunLoopDoBlocks
82 CoreFoundation                 0x9472c __CFRunLoopRun
83 CoreFoundation                 0x93ed0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
84 GraphicsServices               0x3570 GSEventRunModal
85 UIKitCore                      0xb302d0 -[UIApplication _run]
86 UIKitCore                      0xb3584c UIApplicationMain
87 SwiftUI                        0x881530 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:)
88 SwiftUI                        0x8814c0 runApp<A>(_:)
89 SwiftUI                        0x432870 static App.main()
90 Menetrend                      0x6cb8 main + 4331154616 (TripDetailsStop.swift:4331154616)
91 libdyld.dylib                  0x1140 start
```

Comment: Why don’t you download the additional simulator runtimes? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37967439/5508175

Comment: @Andrew  iOS 14.7.1 and 14.8 isn't available as additional simulator runtime

Comment: You are correct, it only goes as high as 14.5....I take it it is not reproducible on that? What version of Xcode did you create your release build with?

Comment: @Andrew, Yes,  it's not reproducible. Xcode 13.2.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE: This is fixed on XCode 13.3. Please update to that version. If you don't want to update, I will leave my answer below.**

I also had the same issue with my app where users reported random crashes on iOS 14 and my crash log looked very similar to yours. The main line that helped me find the solution was `__swift_instantiateConcreteTypeFromMangledName` (which is on line 6 of your crash report and line 7 on mine).

My crash report from simulator:

```
Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x18eb3a0f0 swift::ResolveAsSymbolicReference::operator()(swift::Demangle::SymbolicReferenceKind, swift::Demangle::Directness, int, void const*) + 64
1   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x18eb519ac swift::Demangle::Demangler::demangleSymbolicReference(unsigned char) + 200
2   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x18eb519ac swift::Demangle::Demangler::demangleSymbolicReference(unsigned char) + 200
3   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x18eb4eda0 swift::Demangle::Demangler::demangleType(llvm::StringRef, std::__1::function<swift::Demangle::Node* (swift::Demangle::SymbolicReferenceKind, swift::Demangle::Directness, int, void const*)>) + 184
4   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x18eb3f158 swift_getTypeByMangledNameImpl(swift::MetadataRequest, llvm::StringRef, void const* const*, std::__1::function<swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const* (unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::__1::function<swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const* (swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, unsigned int)>) + 460
5   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x18eb3cc88 swift::swift_getTypeByMangledName(swift::MetadataRequest, llvm::StringRef, void const* const*, std::__1::function<swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const* (unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::__1::function<swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const* (swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, unsigned int)>) + 540
6   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x18eb3ce80 swift_getTypeByMangledNameInContext + 128
7   Asobi                                  0x1040bef40 __swift_instantiateConcreteTypeFromMangledName + 52
8   Asobi                                  0x1040c9eb0 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed Bookmark) -> (@out _ConditionalContent<AnyView, <<opaque return type of View.contextMenu<A>(menuItems:)>>.0>) + 8 [inlined]
9   Asobi                                  0x1040c9eb0 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed Bookmark) -> (@out _ConditionalContent<AnyView, <<opaque return type of View.contextMenu<A>(menuItems:)>>.0>) + 24
10  SwiftUI                                0x1b40abee8 ForEachChild.updateValue() + 852
11  SwiftUI                                0x1b3c8bd5c partial apply for implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 28
12  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b1f4 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 484
13  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b5fc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 320
14  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa010544 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 380
15  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa021210 AGGraphGetValue + 220
16  SwiftUI                                0x1b426ab34 _ConditionalContent<>.ChildView.content.getter + 60
17  SwiftUI                                0x1b426ac5c _ConditionalContent<>.ChildView.value.getter + 260
18  SwiftUI                                0x1b426ad44 protocol witness for Rule.value.getter in conformance _ConditionalContent<A, B><>.ChildView + 40
19  SwiftUI                                0x1b3a76728 implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 68
20  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b1f4 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 484
21  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b5fc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 320
22  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa010544 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 380
23  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa021210 AGGraphGetValue + 220
24  SwiftUI                                0x1b3f45b14 AnyViewList.updateValue() + 56
25  SwiftUI                                0x1b3c2a9a8 partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 20
26  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b1f4 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 484
27  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b5fc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 320
28  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa0104a8 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 224
29  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa021018 AGGraphGetInputValue + 268
30  SwiftUI                                0x1b40a6e44 closure #1 in ForEachState.traitKeys.getter + 120
31  SwiftUI                                0x1b40a729c ForEachState.forEachItem(from:style:do:) + 976
32  SwiftUI                                0x1b40a6db8 ForEachState.traitKeys.getter + 52
33  SwiftUI                                0x1b40ab6cc ForEachList.traitKeys.getter + 20
34  SwiftUI                                0x1b4207b34 Sections.init(from:reifyEmptyHeaders:useFooters:) + 132
35  SwiftUI                                0x1b3e02fb0 SystemListDataSource.init(_:style:minRowHeight:minHeaderHeight:) + 108
36  SwiftUI                                0x1b4134278 InsettableGroupedListBody.Body.body.getter + 564
37  SwiftUI                                0x1b3c72d7c partial apply for closure #1 in ViewBodyAccessor.updateBody(of:changed:) + 28
38  SwiftUI                                0x1b3f41f88 closure #1 in BodyAccessor.setBody(_:) + 44
39  SwiftUI                                0x1b3c6e0e4 ViewBodyAccessor.updateBody(of:changed:) + 1340
40  SwiftUI                                0x1b3f42304 DynamicBody.updateValue() + 268
41  SwiftUI                                0x1b3c8bd5c partial apply for implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 28
42  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b1f4 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 484
43  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b5fc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 320
44  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa010544 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 380
45  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa021210 AGGraphGetValue + 220
46  SwiftUI                                0x1b3e929e4 ListCore.Child.core.getter + 68
47  SwiftUI                                0x1b3e92b1c ListCore.Child.value.getter + 268
48  SwiftUI                                0x1b3a76728 implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 68
49  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b1f4 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 484
50  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b5fc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 320
51  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa010544 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 380
52  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa021210 AGGraphGetValue + 220
53  SwiftUI                                0x1b3f41a60 StaticBody.container.getter + 76
54  SwiftUI                                0x1b3f42070 StaticBody.updateValue() + 116
55  SwiftUI                                0x1b3c8bd5c partial apply for implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 28
56  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b1f4 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 484
57  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b5fc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 320
58  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa010544 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 380
59  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa021210 AGGraphGetValue + 220
60  SwiftUI                                0x1b3977568 specialized UnaryPositionAwareChildGeometry.layout.getter + 24
61  SwiftUI                                0x1b3977648 specialized UnaryPositionAwareChildGeometry.value.getter + 112
62  SwiftUI                                0x1b3a228d4 specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 36
63  SwiftUI                                0x1b3a3d15c partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 24
64  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b1f4 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 484
65  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b5fc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 320
66  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa010544 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 380
67  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa021210 AGGraphGetValue + 220
68  SwiftUI                                0x1b3a6a2e0 LayoutPositionQuery.localPosition.getter + 24
69  SwiftUI                                0x1b3a6a34c LayoutPositionQuery.updateValue() + 36
70  SwiftUI                                0x1b3c2aae4 partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 20
71  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b1f4 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 484
72  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b5fc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 320
73  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa010544 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 380
74  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa021210 AGGraphGetValue + 220
75  SwiftUI                                0x1b41833f0 AnimatableFrameAttribute.updateValue() + 52
76  SwiftUI                                0x1b3c2b0dc partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 20
77  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b1f4 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 484
78  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa00b5fc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 320
79  AttributeGraph                         0x1aa013e60 AG::Subgraph::update(unsigned int) + 864
80  SwiftUI                                0x1b41e66a0 GraphHost.runTransaction() + 164
81  SwiftUI                                0x1b3d80790 ViewGraph.updateOutputs(at:) + 96
82  SwiftUI                                0x1b4153d84 closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 1232
83  SwiftUI                                0x1b414c45c ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 308
84  SwiftUI                                0x1b429d934 _UIHostingView.layoutSubviews() + 168
85  SwiftUI                                0x1b429d960 @objc _UIHostingView.layoutSubviews() + 24
86  UIKitCore                              0x1848c603c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2540
87  QuartzCore                             0x1875fb374 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 288
88  QuartzCore                             0x187601860 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 504
89  UIKitCore                              0x1848b2b34 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 524
90  UIKitCore                              0x183c132bc -[_UISheetPresentationController _sheetLayoutInfoLayout:] + 48
91  UIKitCore                              0x183c0f6bc -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _layout] + 312
92  UIKitCore                              0x183c150fc __54-[_UISheetPresentationController transitionWillBegin:]_block_invoke_2 + 52
93  UIKitCore                              0x1848b9408 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 96
94  UIKitCore                              0x183c15030 __54-[_UISheetPresentationController transitionWillBegin:]_block_invoke.362 + 128
95  UIKitCore                              0x183d391cc -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:] + 264
96  UIKitCore                              0x183d35cbc -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext __runAlongsideAnimations] + 256
97  UIKitCore                              0x1848b91ec __63+[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:]_block_invoke + 28
98  UIKitCore                              0x18488e748 -[UIViewAnimationState _runAlongsideAnimations] + 32
99  UIKitCore                              0x18488d638 -[UIViewAnimationState pop] + 52
100 UIKitCore                              0x18488adf8 +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 64
101 UIKitCore                              0x1848bab84 +[UIView _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 648
102 UIKitCore                              0x1848baff8 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 96
103 UIKitCore                              0x184886940 __50-[UITransitionView _startTransition:withDuration:]_block_invoke.164 + 76
104 UIKitCore                              0x1848bb4f4 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) conditionallyAnimate:withAnimation:layout:completion:] + 88
105 UIKitCore                              0x184886788 -[UITransitionView _startTransition:withDuration:] + 1156
106 UIKitCore                              0x18488607c -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 2416
107 UIKitCore                              0x183d31d34 -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:] + 1476
108 UIKitCore                              0x183d39dc8 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_2 + 72
109 UIKitCore                              0x183e66d6c +[UIInputResponderController _pinInputViewsForInputResponderController:onBehalfOfResponder:duringBlock:] + 104
110 UIKitCore                              0x183d39d48 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke.641 + 176
111 UIKitCore                              0x1848b90f0 +[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:] + 172
112 UIKitCore                              0x183d39bb0 _UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition + 580
113 UIKitCore                              0x183c00b00 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.466 + 2180
114 UIKitCore                              0x184867084 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 64
115 UIKitCore                              0x1843d4728 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 296
116 UIKitCore                              0x1843c48e8 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 200
117 UIKitCore                              0x1843f4cb4 _afterCACommitHandler + 76
118 CoreFoundation                         0x180362190 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
119 CoreFoundation                         0x18035c90c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 556
120 CoreFoundation                         0x18035ce7c __CFRunLoopRun + 992
121 CoreFoundation                         0x18035c58c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
122 GraphicsServices                       0x18b634740 GSEventRunModal + 160
123 UIKitCore                              0x1843c5cbc -[UIApplication _run] + 964
124 UIKitCore                              0x1843caa9c UIApplicationMain + 112
125 SwiftUI                                0x1b41859d8 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 108
126 SwiftUI                                0x1b4185968 runApp<A>(_:) + 160
127 SwiftUI                                0x1b3d7a890 static App.main() + 80
128 Asobi                                  0x1040be9cc static AsobiApp.$main() + 28 (AsobiApp.swift:10) [inlined]
129 Asobi                                  0x1040be9cc main + 40
130 dyld                                   0x104f150f4 start + 520
```

After some digging, I found that this crash report is due to a bug in the Swift compiler on Xcode 13.2 and 13.2.1.

Forum post: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/697070

The main issue here is that using `#if available` (with any iOS 15 specific API which is searchable in your case) in a release build breaks the application for iOS 14 and below with SwiftUI. Apple is aware of this bug and there are no official workarounds at the moment.

Some user-suggested workarounds from the forum post are:

1. Use Xcode 13.1
2. Change the swift compiler to use `-Onone` on release builds
3. Use this workaround https://github.com/gongzhang/swiftui-availability-check-crash

I used the workaround provided in the Github link, but if you want to go the `-Onone` route, I've provided instructions below.

How to set `-Onone`

1. Go to your app target
2. Go to that target's build settings
3. Select `All` in the top bar
4. Search for `optimization`
5. Under `Swift Compiler - Code Generation`, set the `Optimization Level` to `-Onone` under the release section.

Here's my solution to your problem if you don't want to set compiler options, you'll get an Xcode warning, but ignore it for now:

```swift
struct CompatibleSearchBarModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            Group {
                if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                    content.searchable(text: self.$text, prompt: "Placeholder")
                }
            }
        } else {
            content.navigationBarSearch(self.$text, placeholder: "Placeholder", hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling: true, cancelClicked: {text = ""})
        }
    }
}
```

I'd recommend sending a Feedback Assistant report to Apple so they can take a closer look at this bug.

I hope Apple fixes this issue in Xcode 13.3 or another 13.2.x update.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to fix the bug and the crashes are gone!

Comment: Give this person more internet points. Thanks! Awesome answer.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone stumbling upon this:

When using if #available(iOS 14.0, OSX 11.0, *) inside a ViewBuilder, the application crashes when running on the fallback side.

This happens with Xcode versions 13.1 and above. (Currently Xcode 13.2.1)
Tested out with Xcode 13.0 build and crash is gone. We think this is because of compiler optimisation bug in Xcode. For development builds we do not have these crashes.

More here: https://swiftui-lab.com/bug-os-check/